# Max number of shuffled items in php

Tags: php

Let's say I have 30 images.
And 3 sizes, "small", "medium", "large".

I want to output all of them 30 images in a random order, and give a random size class, the small / medium and large one.

At the moment it's like this

```
$random = array("small", "medium", "large");
$images_array = *ALL IMAGES HERE*
shuffle($images_array);

foreach($images_array as $image){ ?>
    <div class="box <?php echo $random[rand(0, count($random) - 1)]; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" /></div>
<?php } ?>
```

All is working fine and I'm indeed getting random classes. BUT!

How can I alter this so that I can set a maximum number for the Large class? I want the large only to appear four times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create an array with 30 values, out of which 4 are `"large"` and the rest are a random combination of `"small"` and `"medium"`. This array, when shuffled, will give you the desired result.

```
<?php
$random = array("large", "large", "large", "large");
for ($i = 0; $i < 26; $i++) {
    $random[] = (rand(1, 2) == 1) ? "small" : "medium";
}
$images_array = *ALL IMAGES HERE*
shuffle($random);
shuffle($images_array);

foreach ($images_array as $key => $image) {
    echo '<div class="box '.$random[$key].'"><img src="'.$image.'" /></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! What if I have an unlimited array of images? Edit, sorry, just remove the for loop =)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a `$counter` variable to count the number of times `large` value was being used. And, if it exceeds simply randomize the value again.

```
<?php
$random = array("small", "medium", "large");
$images_array = *ALL IMAGES HERE*
shuffle($images_array);

$counter = 0;
foreach($images_array as $image){ ?>
    $rand = rand(0, $counter > 3 ? 1 : 2);
    if ($rand == 2) $counter++;  // corresponds to `large`
    echo '<div class="box ' . $random[$rand] .'"><img src="'. $image .'" / </div>';
}
```

Comment: The first line within the `foreach` loop should be changed into `$rand = ($counter < 4) ? rand(0, 2) : rand(0, 1);` and then the third line should be removed. I think it’ll increase the efficiency of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $large = 0;
foreach($images_array as $image){
  $class = $random[rand(0, count($random) - 1)];
  if ($class == 'large') {
    $large++;
    if ($large > 4)
     $class = $random[rand(0, count($random) - 2)];
  }
  echo '<div class="box ' . $class .'"><img src="' . $image . '" /></div>';
} ?>
```